# Form background highlighting on tap/click in Android browser

Tags: android, jquery, browser, yii

I'm trying to adapt a Yii-based website to behave nicely on Android phones.

One issue is that on data entry forms, checkboxes are often smaller than your finger. When you tap a checkbox (or any smallish item) if your finger is a little off, the entire form element will flash highlighted. This is the same behavior as occurs if you touch on an empty area of the form - entire form rectangle flashes orange and the phone makes its tap/click sound.

The checkbox still toggles fine - it just looks visually confusing to see the whole form flash orange when you tap on a checkbox (or its label).

### Update

Maybe a better question is "What is Android browser trying to do by having the form element respond to a tap/click?" If I zoom the form even a tiny bit, then I can tap anywhere, and only the form controls respond (this is the desired behavior). But when zoomed out to 1:1 any taps outside of text fields cause orange flash for the entire form element. The form is designed to fit nicely at 1:1. I was hoping maybe someone with more experience with Android browsers would know why it does this, and perhaps suggest a way to make it behave better.

Comment: you could try increasing the size of the input elements. You never know, the user might have humungous fingers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a side effect of yiiactiveform.js when validateOnSubmit is set to true. In this case, the script adds submit and mouse event handlers that cause the Android browser (and possibly other touch-based browsers) to visually respond to clicks/taps pretty much anywhere on the form outside of a textbox.

I don't know why zooming-in would have any effect on this behavior, but for some reason it does.

Anyway, the simplest solution would be to disable the validateOnSubmit option. Looks like the only other option is to rewrite yiiactiveform.js to not bind to the offending form events. I suppose a custom version could just rely on being explicitly called from a submit button, rather than trying to hook into form events.